# Create heatmap with values from matrix in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've seen heatmaps with values made in various R graphics systems including lattice and base like this:

[image]

I tend to use `ggplot2` a bit and would like to be able to make a heatmap with the corresponding cell values plotted.  Here's the heat map and an attempt using `geom_text`:

```
library(reshape2, ggplot2)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100, 3, 1), ncol=10)
names(dat) <- paste("X", 1:10)
dat2 <- melt(dat, id.var = "X1")
p1 <- ggplot(dat2, aes(as.factor(Var1), Var2, group=Var2)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
    scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") 
p1

#attempt
labs <- c(apply(round(dat[, -2], 1), 2, as.character))
p1 +  geom_text(aes(label=labs), size=1)
```

Normally I can figure out the x and y values to pass but I don't know in this case since this info isn't stored in the data set.  How can I place the text on the heatmap?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599023/r-ordering-the-axis-labels-in-a-ggplot-geom-tile-plot) question has an example of using text with geom_tile that may be useful. Move your aes() call from geom_tile to geom_text

Comment: try `heatmap.2`. refer to similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789549/display-a-matrix-including-the-values-as-a-heatmap

Comment: @TylerRinker Had just hopped on the bus, couldn't provide a proper answer but glad to see you were able to get it sorted.

Comment: Does this help? http://socialdatablog.com/heatmap-tables-with-ggplot2-sort-of/

Comment: @Puriney It seems to me that heatmap.2 is a more powerful option for creating heatmaps than ggplot2, would you agree with this?  I read that "There is no specific heatmap plotting function in ggplot2" on SOURCE: http://learnr.wordpress.com/2010/01/26/ggplot2-quick-heatmap-plotting/

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Key is to add a row identifier to the data and shape it "longer".

**edit Dec 2022 to make code reproducible with R 4.2.2 / ggplot2 3.4.0 and reflect changes in tidyverse semantics**

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100, 3, 1), ncol = 10)
## the matrix needs names
names(dat) <- paste("X", 1:10)

## convert to tibble, add row identifier, and shape "long"
dat2 <-
  dat %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  rownames_to_column("Var1") %>%
  pivot_longer(-Var1, names_to = "Var2", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(
    Var1 = factor(Var1, levels = 1:10),
    Var2 = factor(gsub("V", "", Var2), levels = 1:10)
  )
#> Warning: The `x` argument of `as_tibble.matrix()` must have unique column names if
#> `.name_repair` is omitted as of tibble 2.0.0.
#> ℹ Using compatibility `.name_repair`.

ggplot(dat2, aes(Var1, Var2)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Still useful! I received a warning (in ggplot2 v. 2.2.0) `Ignoring unknown aesthetics: fill`. A bit of tinkering showed that the penultimate line doesn't need a fill value. So this produces the same output for me, without any warning: `geom_text(label = round(dat2$value, 1)))`

Comment: @Gabriel the whole thing was outdated so I updated it

Comment: brilliant, thank you very much. There's some syntax in there I don't recognise... Time to get googling.

Comment: @TylerRinker Thanks much. How can I upgrade this graph to look like this one:

Comment: @TylerRinker: Awesome intro, brother. Any tips how I can bump the game to make the heatmap look like   http://imgur.com/gallery/X2Zxf?

Comment: @Pradeep not sure but that would be nice.  Maybe adding annotations on top and/or combining plots (some text only) using gridExtra, cowplot, and/or ggtree packages.  In any event this is a new question in and of itself that I'd like to know the answer to.  Could you start a new thread?

Comment: it is important to have `geom_text` after `geom_tile` otherwise you get no label and wonder why.

Comment: But the heatmap you ploted is **not** in the same order as in the original `dat` dataframe that you created. How can you make it to look **exactly** like that. I thought that is what OP was asking, and what I thought I would find here. Thanks :)

Comment: The answerer and OP are one and the same.  How is it not in the same order?  If you don't get the same order and you need to make a factor out of the x/y vars and set the levels.

Comment: How would you add a small white border around each number?

Comment: @skan That is a new question worthy of it's own thread.  There are a few approaches that might be possible.

Answer (score 13):

There is another simpler way to make heatmaps with values. You can use [pheatmap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/pheatmap.pdf) to do this.

```
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100, 3, 1), ncol=10)
names(dat) <- paste("X", 1:10)
install.packages('pheatmap') # if not installed already
library(pheatmap)
pheatmap(dat, display_numbers = T)
```

This will give you a plot like this

[image: Heatmap with values]

If you want to remove clustering and use your color scheme you can do

```
pheatmap(dat, display_numbers = T, color = colorRampPalette(c('white','red'))(100), cluster_rows = F, cluster_cols = F, fontsize_number = 15)
```

[image: heatmap without clustering and red white colors]

You can also change the fontsize, format, and color of the displayed numbers.