# Display the numbers in complex heatmap

Tags: r, heatmap, complexheatmap

hi I´m trying to display the numbers of a df on a HEATMAP

I have this df

```
> matrinrmatr
      ce   n1   n2   n3   ca
sn  6.47 1.89 0.52   NA   NA
inn 6.47 3.94   NA   NA   NA
pn  6.93   NA   NA   NA   NA
bn  6.40 6.63 5.08 5.56 2.73
cn  7.67 2.13 2.03 5.70   NA
vn  7.29 3.37 2.76 3.74 2.18
cin 5.57 3.61 2.51 3.72 2.18
```

and i try to make a heatmap using the following script

```
hmmatrinr <- Heatmap(matrinrmatr, 
                     row_title="Grupos", 
                     column_title="camadas", 
                     col=colheatp, 
                     cluster_rows=FALSE, 
                     cluster_columns=FALSE, 
                     show_column_dend=FALSE, 
                     width=unit(6, "cm"), 
                     height=unit(9, "cm"), 
                     heatmap_legend_param=list(
                       title="Score", 
                       at=c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), 
                       legend_height=unit(8, "cm"), 
                       grid_width=unit(0.5, "cm")
                     ), 
                     layer_fun <- function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) {
                       grid.text
                       (sprintf("%s", 
                                pindex(matrinrmatr, i, j), 
                                x=x, y=y, 
                                gp=gpar(fontsize=10, col="grey")))
                     }
)
```

I  had this without the layer_fun part
a heatmap without the numbers on the cells
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AMoV.png

the problem is with layer_fun part

it gave me

```
Error in sprintf("%s", pindex(matrinrmatr, i, j), x = x, y = y, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10,  : 
  arguments cannot be recycled to the same length
```

I  tried to use

```
layer_fun <- function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) {
  grid.text
  (sprintf(
    "%f", 
    pindex(matrinrmatr, i, j), x=x, y=y))
}
```

and the result was

```
 Warning message:
    In sprintf("%f", pindex(matrinrmatr, i, j), x = x, y = y) :
      2 arguments not used by format '%f
```

Also tried

```
layer_fun <- function(j, i, x, y, width, height, fill) {
  grid.text
  (sprintf("%s", 
           pindex(matrinrmatr, i, j), x=x, y=y))
}
```

and gave me

```
Warning message:
In sprintf("%s", pindex(matrinrmatr, i, j), x = x, y = y) :
  2 arguments not used by format '%s'
```

without the numbers

I will be grateful if someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290364/heatmap-with-values-ggplot2

Comment: You should make this more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038).