# How to add bounding box to a specific area in ggplot2 heatmap?

Tags: r, heatmap

I use an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11599023/r-ordering-the-axis-labels-in-a-ggplot-geom-tile-plot). My question is how can I add a specific bounding box to this heatmap, such as add a red line box to the top left four tiles?

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape)
require(scales)

mydf <- data.frame(industry = c('all industries','steel','cars'), 
    'all regions' = c(250,150,100), americas = c(150,90,60), 
     europe = c(150,60,40), check.names = FALSE)
mydf

mymelt <- melt(mydf, id.var = c('industry'))
mymelt

ggplot(mymelt, aes(x = industry, y = variable, fill = value)) +
    geom_tile() + geom_text(aes(fill = mymelt$value, label = mymelt$value))
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick and dirty (some hard-coding) possibility is to use `geom_rect`, where the positions are given by the numerical values of the levels of x and y variables to be bound with a box, plus/minus an offset.

```
ggplot(mymelt, aes(x = industry, y = variable, fill = value, label = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = 1 - 0.5, xmax = 2 + 0.5, ymin = 2 - 0.5, ymax = 3 + 0.5),
               fill = "transparent", color = "red", size = 1.5)
```

[image]

A less hard-coded version:

```
# convert x and y variables to factors
ind <- as.factor(mymelt$industry)
vars <- as.factor(mymelt$variable)

# numeric version of the levels to be bound by a box
xmin <- unique(as.numeric(ind[ind == "all industries"]))
xmax <- unique(as.numeric(ind[ind == "cars"]))

ymin <- unique(as.numeric(vars[vars == "americas"]))
ymax <- unique(as.numeric(vars[vars == "europe"]))

# set offset
offset <- 0.5

ggplot(mymelt, aes(x = industry, y = variable, fill = value, label = value)) +
  geom_tile() +
  geom_text() +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = xmin - offset,
                xmax = xmax + offset,
                ymin = ymin - offset,
                ymax = ymax + offset),
            fill = "transparent", color = "red", size = 1.5)
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help, Henrik! Additionally, I'm wondering how can I add a text to this red box? That will be wonderful.