# ggplot2 many levels in geom_tile, specific order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I imported my data into R and melted it to make a `geom_tile` heat map.  My input file looks like this:

```
sample,variable,value
chickenpox,person1,7
measles,person1,5
mumps,person1,2
diptheria,person1,8
chickenpox,person2,3
measles,person2,4
mumps,person2,0
diptheria,person2,8
chickenpox,person3,1
measles,person3,2
mumps,person3,7
diptheria,person3,2
chickenpox,person4,1
measles,person4,2
mumps,person4,5
diptheria,person4,1
```

Then I run:

```
b<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE)
q <- ggplot(data=b, aes(x=variable, y=sample, fill=value))
q + geom_tile()
```

And I am given this picture:
[image: Imgur]

The problem is: The y axis automatically alphabetizes it.  My data shouldn't be in  alphabetical order, but in a specific order. How can I have the heat map display `sample` as the `y-axis` and `variable` as the `x-axis`, while maintaining the imported order of `sample`?

**It would be a major hassle for me to retype the sample column for each of the 460 factors that sample has for each person.**

There has to be a faster way.

Comment: Could you add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Comment: If you just want to change the order, use `scale_y_discrete` to specify it. Something like `ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=sample, fill=value)) + geom_tile() + scale_y_discrete(limits=unique(df$sample))` should work.

Comment: Thanks shadow!  That made it work!